# post_type page redirect to random post

Tags: wordpress, redirect, custom-post-type

I created a post_type.
for some reason when i go to
`http://localhost/post_type/`
its redirect me to
`http://localhost/post_type/random_post/`

where is my mistake ?

my post_type code is:

```
function bookworm_blog_cpt() {
    global $book; // name of the post_type
    register_post_type( "{$book}", array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => "{$book}",
            'singular_name' => "{$book}",
            'menu_name'          => $book ,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => $book ),
            ),
        'description' => "{$book}s which we will be discussing on this blog.",
        'public' => true, 'show_ui' => true,
        'menu_position' => 20,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor',
                            'post-formats',
                            'tags', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields' ) ,
        'has_archive'   => true,
    ));

    add_filter( "manage_edit-{$book}_columns", 'my_edit_book_columns' ) ;
    function my_edit_book_columns( $columns ) {
        global $book;
        $columns = array(
            'cb' => '&lt;input type="checkbox" />',
            'title' => __( "{$book}" ),
            "{$book}_tag" => __( "{$book}_tag" ),
            //'genre' => __( 'Genre' ),
            "{$book}_cat" => __( "{$book}_cat" ),
            'date' => __( 'Date' ),
            'mime_type' => __( 'mime_type' )
        );
        return $columns;
    }
}
```

and i dont have any code in home page, and `single-post_type.php` is eampty.

thanks for the help.

**edit:** the problem is the same when i use `Custom Post Type UI` plugin, so i dont know where is the problem for.

**edit2:**  it was probably something in my other files, i re installed wordpress and the error is gone.

Comment: Try with clearing the browser cache, flush the rewrite rule by resetting the permalinks

Comment: from the admin dashboard, Settings > Permanlink

Comment: @jogesh_pi I reset it, no change.